# standardize addresses for "nominatim"

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV (result of a cleaning) which has columns: Region, pronvincia, municipality and address. I would like to get the latitude and longitude for each row. I suppose it is necessary to create a method to standardize addresses through regular expressions, apply it to each line and create a Csv to be fed to "nominatim", but I don't know where to start (I tried to do research but I don't know the name of this type of procedure).
Can anyone with experience in this type of operations guide me?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example and a desired result?

Comment: I have no examples to provide, suppose I have a csv with the columns: State, Region, province and municipality and I wanted a resulting identical daset but with the addition of the latitude and longitude columns. The streets can have abbreviations.